# How to make the child element display on top of parent's scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css

I have a custom dropdown inside a table cell. The table that contains that cell is in a wrapper that is supposed to scroll horizontally but not vertically. The horizontal scrolling works fine but I found out that

```
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:visible;
```

won't work together, according to the specs. The dropdown contents are displayed beneath the parent container's scrollbars. I'm trying to make the dropdown display on top of the horizontal scrollbars.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GvUT/) of what I have so far. I'm not sure how I can make the vertical scrollbar not appear when you click on the dropdowns. I'm thinking of just cloning the dropdown menu, appending it to the end of the body and then positioning it to where the original is so it would just basically float over everything and not affect the container of the table. Thing is, I would have to think of a way to make it scroll with the table when the container is scrolled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible because the `.wrapper` wrap all the content. SO if you want to the `.content` overlap the scrollbar, the `.content` must be outside of `.wrapper`. I'll send you the demo for this soon. Be wait!

Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/92gey/

Comment: Hi @Bob thanks for your answer. This is like what I was thinking of. I was actually hoping for a cleaner way to do this. Also, the menu doesn't move with the scrolling of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or if you want that the dropdown should come on top of horizontal bar, then you need to set, "top" property in below css:

Some thing like this:

```
.custom-dropdown .contents { 
    top:-25px;
}
```

Comment: the dropdown should display over the scrollbar. thanks for your answer though.